# Como retornar apenas o registro mais antigo com mais de 1 status Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-select

estou precisando de uma ajuda!

Estou com uma dificuldade em gerar uma consulta.
O cenário é o seguinte:

Possuo duas tabelas: ATIVIDADES e STATUS
ATIVIDADES:
(id, num_atividade, dt_envio) PK(id)

| id | num_atividade | dt_envio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16316 | 1-NU8W75 | 2022-01-20 16:49:00.000 |
| 16317 | 1-NU9HZO | 2022-01-21 09:38:00.000 |
| 16318 | 1-NU9I0B | 2022-01-21 09:40:00.000 |
| 16319 | 1-NU9II5 | 2022-01-21 11:24:00.000 |
| 16320 | 1-NU9X9Y | 2022-01-21 12:19:00.000 |
| 16321 | 1-NU9XB2 | 2022-01-22 12:37:00.000 |

STATUS:
(id, num_atividade_id, status, dt_registro) PK (id) FK(num_atividade_id)

| id | num_atividade_id | status | dt_registro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4260 | 16316 | Pendente | 2022-01-28 20:39:48.103 |
| 4640 | 16316 | Concluído | 2022-01-29 10:10:42.743 |
| 4261 | 16317 | Pendente | 2022-01-28 20:39:48.110 |
| 4641 | 16317 | Concluído | 2022-01-29 10:10:42.960 |
| 4262 | 16318 | Pendente | 2022-01-28 20:39:48.117 |
| 4642 | 16318 | Concluído | 2022-01-29 10:10:42.967 |
| 4264 | 16320 | Pendente | 2022-01-28 20:39:48.130 |
| 4644 | 16320 | Concluído | 2022-01-29 10:10:43.113 |
| 4265 | 16321 | Pendente | 2022-01-30 20:39:48.150 |

Eu preciso construir uma consulta que me retorne o dt_envio mais antigo das atividades que estão somente em aberto, ou seja, tem apenas o status pendente na tabela status.

```
SELECT top 1 base.id, base.num_atividade, base.dt_envio 
FROM ATIVIDADES base, STATUS st 
WHERE st.num_atividade_id = base.id AND st.status = 'Pendente';
```

Tentei efetuar a consulta acima, porém ele está me trazendo o registro que também contém o status concluído e eu preciso que retorne apenas o registro que esteja somente pendente.

Desde já agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você pode utilizar o operador *Exists* para verificar se a atividade possui alguma linha com o status diferente de 'Pendente':

```
SELECT top 1 base.id, base.num_atividade, base.dt_envio 
FROM ATIVIDADES base
WHERE 
    not exists
        (select 1 from STATUS st 
         where 
             st.num_atividade_id = base.id AND 
             st.status <> 'Pendente')
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou perfeitamente!